# PHP preg_match_all fails on binary data

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to find all objects in a pdf file. I'm using the following regular expression which returns 2 matches out of 700 I know to exist:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+ [0-9]+ obj\r\n(.*?)endobj/s', $data, $matches);
```

Using the same regular expression works in python, but this seems to fail on windows and linux if using PHP to match. Is this just a bug, or is there some flag I need to be using that I'm unaware of?

Comment: `preg_match` won't work on binary right out of the box.  Most likely, you will need to use a PDF parsing library in PHP first.  Once you have clear text in hand, then use `preg_match`.

Comment: Use `\r?\n` to make it work for both Linux as well as Windows line endings. Also your sentence isn't very clear where you say it works in Python but not in windows or Linux. Also, can you post some samples of data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suspect this code is intended to *be* part of a PDF parsing library: it's looking for strings that form part of the structure of a PDF.

Comment: @IMSoP you're correct, this is intended to be part of a PDF parsing library.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Using windows or linux PHP returns only 2 matches, however in windows or linux Python returns hundreds using the same expression.

Comment: @AustinMaier: Can you post some sample data in some online tool like regex101 where Python matches plenty of data vs PHP matching very few? That sample data should help us in helping you back.

Comment: In trying this I've discovered something very interesting. When I experienced the issue I was using file_get_contents() to read the file. When I was trying with online regex services it was working. I created an html page where I could submit to my own server with the same regex and it matched it successfully. Seemingly reading the file is causing an issue somehow.

Comment: @AustinMaier: Good to know you caught your issue which wasn't regex specific. Let us know for any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue had to do with the size of the stream in the file. When I was reading the file with file_get_contents and running preg_match_all on it, I was getting a backtrack limit error from preg_match, however when I copied the text out of notepad++ and pasted into a web form that fed the same regex I did not. It turns out when I pasted it, it was reading as UTF8, and thus was fewer characters, so I didn't reach the backtrack limit. The stream was sized just big enough that it would work as UTF8, but I would hit the backtrack limit on the slightly longer ANSI text.

Ultimately I ended up changing the regex to search for just the start of the object, then used strpos to find the end. This turned out to be a much more efficient method than ([0-9]+ [0-9]+) obj(.*?)endobj